# UIFlowLayoutRow watchdog termination crash on iOS

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, crash

My app metrics shows that some devices crash with the following information:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Process Visibility: Foreground
Watchdog Event: scene-update (other reports has scene-create)
Watchdog Visibility: Background
Termination Code: 0x8badf00d
```

Stack traces:

```
UIKitCore  -[_UIFlowLayoutRow layoutRow]
UIKitCore  -[_UIFlowLayoutRow layoutRow]
UIKitCore  -[_UIFlowLayoutSection computeLayoutInRect:forSection:invalidating:invalidationContext:]
UIKitCore  __76-[UICollectionViewFlowLayout _updateItemsLayoutForRect:allowsPartialUpdate:]_block_invoke
CoreFoundation  __NSARRAY_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
CoreFoundation  -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]
UIKitCore  -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout _updateItemsLayoutForRect:allowsPartialUpdate:]
UIKitCore  -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout _fetchItemsInfoForRect:]
UIKitCore  -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout prepareLayout]
UIKitCore  -[UICollectionViewData _prepareToLoadData]
UIKitCore  -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:]
UIKitCore  -[UICollectionViewData layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:]
UIKitCore  -[UICollectionView _indexPathForItemAtPoint:]
UIKitCore  -[UICollectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:]
MyApp  - [MyAppCollectionViewController gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:]
UIKitCore  -[UIGestureRecognizer _delegateShouldReceiveTouch:forEvent:]
UIKitCore  -[UIGestureRecognizer _internalShouldReceiveTouch:forEvent:recognizerView:]
UIKitCore  __80-[UITouchesEvent _addGestureRecognizersForGestureOwner:toTouch:forContinuation:]_block_invoke
UIKitCore  __70-[UITouchesEvent _collectGestureRecognizersForGestureOwner:withBlock:]_block_invoke
UIKitCore  -[UITouchesEvent _collectGestureRecognizersForGestureOwner:withBlock:]
UIKitCore  -[UITouchesEvent _addGestureRecognizersForGestureOwner:toTouch:forContinuation:]
UIKitCore  -[UITouchesEvent _addTouch:forDelayedDelivery:]
UIKitCore  _AddTouchToEventAndDetermineIfNeedsCancel
UIKitCore  ____updateTouchesWithDigitizerEventAndDetermineIfShouldSend_block_invoke.51
CoreFoundation  __NSDICTIONARY_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
CoreFoundation  ____NSDictionaryEnumerate_block_invoke_2
CoreFoundation  CFBasicHashApply
CoreFoundation  __NSDictionaryEnumerate
UIKitCore  __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue
UIKitCore  __processEventQueue
UIKitCore  __eventFetcherSourceCallback
CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoSource0
CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoSources0
CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun
CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GraphicsServices  GSEventRunModal
UIKitCore  -[UIApplication _run]
UIKitCore  UIApplicationMain

Thread ID: 0
Stacktrace:
libsystem_kernel.dylib  poll
MyApp  pollset_work(grpc_pollset*, grpc_pollset_worker**, grpc_core::Timestamp)
MyApp  cq_next(grpc_completion_queue*, gpr_timespec, void*)
MyApp  __27-[GRPCCompletionQueue init]_block_invoke_2
libdispatch.dylib  _dispatch_call_block_and_release
libdispatch.dylib  _dispatch_client_callout
libdispatch.dylib  _dispatch_root_queue_drain
libdispatch.dylib  _dispatch_worker_thread2
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_wqthread
libsystem_pthread.dylib  start_wqthread

Thread ID: 1
Stacktrace:
libsystem_pthread.dylib  start_wqthread

Thread ID: 2
Stacktrace:
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg2_trap
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg2_internal
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg_overwrite
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg
CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort
CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun
CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific
Foundation  -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]
Foundation  -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:]
UIKitCore  -[UIEventFetcher threadMain]
Foundation  __NSThread__start__
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_start
libsystem_pthread.dylib  thread_start

Thread ID: 3
Stacktrace:
libsystem_pthread.dylib  start_wqthread

Thread ID: 4
Stacktrace:
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg2_trap
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg2_internal
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg_overwrite
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg
MyApp  crashpad::MachMessageWithDeadline(mach_msg_header_t*, int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned long long, unsigned int, bool)
MyApp  crashpad::MachMessageServer::Run()
MyApp  crashpad::(anonymous namespace)::CrashHandler::ThreadMain()
MyApp  crashpad::Thread::ThreadEntryThunk(void*)
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_start
libsystem_pthread.dylib  thread_start

Thread ID: 5
Stacktrace:
libsystem_pthread.dylib  start_wqthread

Thread ID: 6
Stacktrace:
libsystem_kernel.dylib  semaphore_timedwait_trap
libdispatch.dylib  _dispatch_sema4_timedwait
libdispatch.dylib  _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow
MyApp  crashpad::Semaphore::TimedWait(double)
MyApp  crashpad::internal::WorkerThreadImpl::ThreadMain()
MyApp  crashpad::Thread::ThreadEntryThunk(void*)
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_start
libsystem_pthread.dylib  thread_start

Thread ID: 7
Stacktrace:
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg2_trap
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg2_internal
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg_overwrite
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg
CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort
CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun
CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific
CFNetwork  _CFURLStorageSessionDisableCache
Foundation  __NSThread__start__
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_start
libsystem_pthread.dylib  thread_start

Thread ID: 8
Stacktrace:
libsystem_kernel.dylib  semaphore_timedwait_trap
libdispatch.dylib  _dispatch_sema4_timedwait
libdispatch.dylib  _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow
MyApp  crashpad::Semaphore::TimedWait(double)
MyApp  crashpad::internal::WorkerThreadImpl::ThreadMain()
MyApp  crashpad::Thread::ThreadEntryThunk(void*)
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_start
libsystem_pthread.dylib  thread_start

Thread ID: 9
Stacktrace:
libsystem_kernel.dylib  __psynch_cvwait
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_cond_wait
MyApp  absl::synchronization_internal::PthreadWaiter::Wait(absl::synchronization_internal::KernelTimeout)
MyApp  AbslInternalPerThreadSemWait
MyApp  absl::CondVar::WaitCommon(absl::Mutex*, absl::synchronization_internal::KernelTimeout)
MyApp  gpr_cv_wait
MyApp  grpc_core::Executor::ThreadMain(void*)
MyApp  Thread::ThreadBody(void*)
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_start
libsystem_pthread.dylib  thread_start

Thread ID: 10
Stacktrace:
libsystem_kernel.dylib  __psynch_cvwait
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_cond_wait
MyApp  absl::synchronization_internal::PthreadWaiter::Wait(absl::synchronization_internal::KernelTimeout)
MyApp  AbslInternalPerThreadSemWait
MyApp  absl::CondVar::WaitCommon(absl::Mutex*, absl::synchronization_internal::KernelTimeout)
MyApp  gpr_cv_wait
MyApp  grpc_core::Executor::ThreadMain(void*)
MyApp  Thread::ThreadBody(void*)
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_start
libsystem_pthread.dylib  thread_start

Thread ID: 11
Stacktrace:
libsystem_kernel.dylib  __psynch_cvwait
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_cond_wait
MyApp  absl::synchronization_internal::PthreadWaiter::Wait(absl::synchronization_internal::KernelTimeout)
MyApp  AbslInternalPerThreadSemWait
MyApp  absl::CondVar::WaitCommon(absl::Mutex*, absl::synchronization_internal::KernelTimeout)
MyApp  gpr_cv_wait
MyApp  timer_thread(void*)
MyApp  Thread::ThreadBody(void*)
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_start
libsystem_pthread.dylib  thread_start

Thread ID: 12
Stacktrace:
libsystem_kernel.dylib  __psynch_cvwait
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_cond_wait
MyApp  absl::synchronization_internal::PthreadWaiter::Wait(absl::synchronization_internal::KernelTimeout)
MyApp  AbslInternalPerThreadSemWait
MyApp  absl::CondVar::WaitCommon(absl::Mutex*, absl::synchronization_internal::KernelTimeout)
MyApp  grpc_event_engine::experimental::OriginalThreadPool::Queue::Step()
MyApp  grpc_event_engine::experimental::OriginalThreadPool::StartThread()
MyApp  Thread::ThreadBody(void*)
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_start
libsystem_pthread.dylib  thread_start

Thread ID: 13
Stacktrace:
libsystem_kernel.dylib  __psynch_cvwait
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_cond_wait
MyApp  absl::synchronization_internal::PthreadWaiter::Wait(absl::synchronization_internal::KernelTimeout)
MyApp  AbslInternalPerThreadSemWait
MyApp  absl::CondVar::WaitCommon(absl::Mutex*, absl::synchronization_internal::KernelTimeout)
MyApp  grpc_event_engine::experimental::OriginalThreadPool::Queue::Step()
MyApp  grpc_event_engine::experimental::OriginalThreadPool::StartThread()
MyApp  Thread::ThreadBody(void*)
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_start
libsystem_pthread.dylib  thread_start

Thread ID: 14
Stacktrace:
libsystem_kernel.dylib  __psynch_cvwait
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_cond_wait
MyApp  absl::synchronization_internal::PthreadWaiter::Wait(absl::synchronization_internal::KernelTimeout)
MyApp  AbslInternalPerThreadSemWait
MyApp  absl::CondVar::WaitCommon(absl::Mutex*, absl::synchronization_internal::KernelTimeout)
MyApp  grpc_event_engine::experimental::OriginalThreadPool::Queue::Step()
MyApp  grpc_event_engine::experimental::OriginalThreadPool::StartThread()
MyApp  Thread::ThreadBody(void*)
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_start
libsystem_pthread.dylib  thread_start

Thread ID: 15
Stacktrace:
libsystem_kernel.dylib  __psynch_cvwait
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_cond_wait
MyApp  absl::synchronization_internal::PthreadWaiter::Wait(absl::synchronization_internal::KernelTimeout)
MyApp  AbslInternalPerThreadSemWait
MyApp  absl::CondVar::WaitCommon(absl::Mutex*, absl::synchronization_internal::KernelTimeout)
MyApp  grpc_event_engine::experimental::OriginalThreadPool::Queue::Step()
MyApp  grpc_event_engine::experimental::OriginalThreadPool::StartThread()
MyApp  Thread::ThreadBody(void*)
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_start
libsystem_pthread.dylib  thread_start

Thread ID: 16
Stacktrace:
libsystem_kernel.dylib  __psynch_cvwait
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_cond_wait
MyApp  absl::synchronization_internal::PthreadWaiter::Wait(absl::synchronization_internal::KernelTimeout)
MyApp  AbslInternalPerThreadSemWait
MyApp  absl::CondVar::WaitCommon(absl::Mutex*, absl::synchronization_internal::KernelTimeout)
MyApp  grpc_event_engine::experimental::OriginalThreadPool::Queue::Step()
MyApp  grpc_event_engine::experimental::OriginalThreadPool::StartThread()
MyApp  Thread::ThreadBody(void*)
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_start
libsystem_pthread.dylib  thread_start

Thread ID: 17
Stacktrace:
libsystem_kernel.dylib  __psynch_cvwait
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_cond_wait
MyApp  absl::synchronization_internal::PthreadWaiter::Wait(absl::synchronization_internal::KernelTimeout)
MyApp  AbslInternalPerThreadSemWait
MyApp  absl::CondVar::WaitCommon(absl::Mutex*, absl::synchronization_internal::KernelTimeout)
MyApp  grpc_event_engine::experimental::OriginalThreadPool::Queue::Step()
MyApp  grpc_event_engine::experimental::OriginalThreadPool::StartThread()
MyApp  Thread::ThreadBody(void*)
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_start
libsystem_pthread.dylib  thread_start

Thread ID: 18
Stacktrace:
libsystem_kernel.dylib  __psynch_cvwait
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_cond_wait
MyApp  absl::synchronization_internal::PthreadWaiter::TimedWait(absl::synchronization_internal::KernelTimeout)
MyApp  absl::synchronization_internal::PthreadWaiter::Wait(absl::synchronization_internal::KernelTimeout)
MyApp  AbslInternalPerThreadSemWait
MyApp  absl::CondVar::WaitCommon(absl::Mutex*, absl::synchronization_internal::KernelTimeout)
MyApp  absl::CondVar::WaitWithTimeout(absl::Mutex*, absl::Duration)
MyApp  grpc_event_engine::experimental::TimerManager::WaitUntil(grpc_core::Timestamp)
MyApp  grpc_event_engine::experimental::TimerManager::MainLoop()
MyApp  Thread::ThreadBody(void*)
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_start
libsystem_pthread.dylib  thread_start

Thread ID: 19
Stacktrace:
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg2_trap
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg2_internal
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg_overwrite
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg
CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort
CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun
CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific
CoreFoundation  _legacyStreamRunLoop_workThread
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_start
libsystem_pthread.dylib  thread_start

Thread ID: 20
Stacktrace:
libsystem_kernel.dylib  __select
CoreFoundation  __CFSocketManager
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_start
libsystem_pthread.dylib  thread_start

Thread ID: 21
Stacktrace:
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg2_trap
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg2_internal
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg_overwrite
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg
CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort
CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun
CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific
CFNetwork  _CFURLStorageSessionDisableCache
Foundation  __NSThread__start__
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_start
libsystem_pthread.dylib  thread_start

Thread ID: 22
Stacktrace:
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg2_trap
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg2_internal
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg_overwrite
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg
CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort
CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun
CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific
Foundation  -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]
MyAppWebView  base::MessagePumpNSRunLoop::DoRun(base::MessagePump::Delegate*)
MyAppWebView  base::MessagePumpCFRunLoopBase::Run(base::MessagePump::Delegate*)
MyAppWebView  base::sequence_manager::internal::ThreadControllerWithMessagePumpImpl::Run(bool, base::TimeDelta)
MyAppWebView  base::RunLoop::Run(base::Location const&)
MyAppWebView  base::Thread::Run(base::RunLoop*)
MyAppWebView  base::Thread::ThreadMain()
MyAppWebView  base::(anonymous namespace)::ThreadFunc(void*)
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_start
libsystem_pthread.dylib  thread_start

Thread ID: 23
Stacktrace:
libsystem_kernel.dylib  kevent64
MyAppWebView  base::MessagePumpKqueue::DoInternalWork(base::MessagePump::Delegate*, base::MessagePump::Delegate::NextWorkInfo*)
MyAppWebView  base::MessagePumpKqueue::Run(base::MessagePump::Delegate*)
MyAppWebView  base::sequence_manager::internal::ThreadControllerWithMessagePumpImpl::Run(bool, base::TimeDelta)
MyAppWebView  base::RunLoop::Run(base::Location const&)
MyAppWebView  base::Thread::Run(base::RunLoop*)
MyAppWebView  base::internal::ServiceThread::Run(base::RunLoop*)
MyAppWebView  base::Thread::ThreadMain()
MyAppWebView  base::(anonymous namespace)::ThreadFunc(void*)
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_start
libsystem_pthread.dylib  thread_start

Thread ID: 24
Stacktrace:
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg2_trap
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg2_internal
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg_overwrite
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg
MyAppWebView  base::WaitableEvent::TimedWaitImpl(base::TimeDelta)
MyAppWebView  base::WaitableEvent::TimedWait(base::TimeDelta)
MyAppWebView  base::internal::WorkerThread::Delegate::WaitForWork(base::WaitableEvent*)
MyAppWebView  base::internal::WorkerThread::RunWorker()(
MyAppWebView  base::internal::WorkerThread::RunPooledWorker()
MyAppWebView  base::internal::WorkerThread::ThreadMain()
MyAppWebView  base::(anonymous namespace)::ThreadFunc(void*)
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_start
libsystem_pthread.dylib  thread_start

Thread ID: 25
Stacktrace:
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg2_trap
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg2_internal
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg_overwrite
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg
MyAppWebView  base::WaitableEvent::TimedWaitImpl(base::TimeDelta)
MyAppWebView  base::WaitableEvent::TimedWait(base::TimeDelta)
MyAppWebView  base::internal::WorkerThread::Delegate::WaitForWork(base::WaitableEvent*)
MyAppWebView  base::internal::WorkerThread::RunWorker()
MyAppWebView  base::internal::WorkerThread::RunBackgroundPooledWorker()
MyAppWebView  base::internal::WorkerThread::ThreadMain()
MyAppWebView  base::(anonymous namespace)::ThreadFunc(void*)
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_start
libsystem_pthread.dylib  thread_start

Thread ID: 26
Stacktrace:
libsystem_kernel.dylib  kevent64
MyAppWebView  base::MessagePumpKqueue::DoInternalWork(base::MessagePump::Delegate*, base::MessagePump::Delegate::NextWorkInfo*)
MyAppWebView  base::MessagePumpKqueue::Run(base::MessagePump::Delegate*)
MyAppWebView  base::sequence_manager::internal::ThreadControllerWithMessagePumpImpl::Run(bool, base::TimeDelta)
MyAppWebView  base::RunLoop::Run(base::Location const&)
MyAppWebView  base::Thread::Run(base::RunLoop*)
MyAppWebView  web::WebSubThread::IOThreadRun(base::RunLoop*)
MyAppWebView  base::Thread::ThreadMain()
MyAppWebView  base::(anonymous namespace)::ThreadFunc(void*)
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_start
libsystem_pthread.dylib  thread_start

Thread ID: 27
Stacktrace:
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg2_trap
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg2_internal
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg_overwrite
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg
MyAppWebView  base::WaitableEvent::TimedWaitImpl(base::TimeDelta)
MyAppWebView  base::WaitableEvent::TimedWait(base::TimeDelta)
MyAppWebView  base::internal::WorkerThread::Delegate::WaitForWork(base::WaitableEvent*)
MyAppWebView  base::internal::WorkerThread::RunWorker()
MyAppWebView  base::internal::WorkerThread::RunPooledWorker()
MyAppWebView  base::internal::WorkerThread::ThreadMain()
MyAppWebView  base::(anonymous namespace)::ThreadFunc(void*)
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_start
libsystem_pthread.dylib  thread_start

Thread ID: 28
Stacktrace:
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg2_trap
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg2_internal
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg_overwrite
libsystem_kernel.dylib  mach_msg
MyAppWebView  base::WaitableEvent::TimedWaitImpl(base::TimeDelta)
MyAppWebView  base::WaitableEvent::TimedWait(base::TimeDelta)
MyAppWebView  base::internal::WorkerThread::Delegate::WaitForWork
MyAppWebView  base::internal::WorkerThread::RunWorker()
MyAppWebView  base::internal::WorkerThread::RunBackgroundPooledWorker()
MyAppWebView  base::internal::WorkerThread::ThreadMain()
MyAppWebView  base::(anonymous namespace)::ThreadFunc(void*)
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_start
libsystem_pthread.dylib  thread_start

Thread ID: 29
Stacktrace:
libsystem_kernel.dylib  __psynch_cvwait
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_cond_wait
MyApp  absl::synchronization_internal::PthreadWaiter::TimedWait(absl::synchronization_internal::KernelTimeout)
MyApp  absl::synchronization_internal::PthreadWaiter::Wait(absl::synchronization_internal::KernelTimeout)
MyApp  AbslInternalPerThreadSemWait
MyApp  absl::CondVar::WaitCommon(absl::Mutex*, absl::synchronization_internal::KernelTimeout)
MyApp  absl::CondVar::WaitWithTimeout(absl::Mutex*, absl::Duration)
MyApp  gpr_cv_wait
MyApp  timer_thread(void*)
MyApp  Thread::ThreadBody(void*)
libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_start
libsystem_pthread.dylib  thread_start
```

There is a similar unanswered question on [Apple Developer forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/704248). I checked [Apple Watchdog termination documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/addressing-watchdog-terminations) but it didn't help much.

I tried to reproduce it on my iPhone or simulator but I couldn't. Did anyone have the same issue before and how did you fix it?

Comment: You have shown a stack trace, but what is the exception message?  There is no mention of the watchdog in the trace.

Comment: I updated the description with all the information I have. Thanks so much.

Comment: Watchdog transgressions occur because the main thread was blocked.  It is unlikely to be the row layout code itself. I can see from the other threads that a number of them were waiting on semaphores.  You need to examine your code for potential deadlocks. Do you dispatch any code synchronously onto the main thread? Do you perform any network operations or other asynchronous operations in the gesture recogniser?

Comment: A network request is sent in the gesture recogniser indeed, under certain conditions. I tried to reproduce the bug on simulator. I kept touching the collection items as fast as I can and verified the network requests are sent for every touch gesture but the crash didn't occur. Do you have any recommendations on how to reproduce such a crash?

Comment: Can you show the relevant code from your gesture recognizer?

Comment: Hi Paul, I disabled the gesture recognizer network request but it didn't fix the bug. I found a fix and added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is related to the layout configuration:

1. I implemented a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` where `estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize`
2. Each cell implemented its own `preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes`.
3. I implemented a custom `UICollectionViewController`. It implemented `UICollectionViewDelegate` and returned NO for `@selector(collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:)` so that the `UICollectionView` uses automatic cell sizing, except for a special cell where I wanted the `UICollectionView` to use manual sizing by calling UICollectionViewDelegate's `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`.

My guess is that the new logic which returned `YES` in `@selector(collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:)` for the special cell somehow affected some other cells and caused the crash. I fixed it by getting rid of the manual cell sizing logic. Now, `UICollectionViewDelegate` returns NO in `@selector(collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:)` for all cells and automatic cell sizing is used for all cells.